# expression "something beyond your kin"

Tags: expressions, errors

I heard the expression "something is beyond your kin", see an example:

> Woman, you're playing with forces beyond your kin.

I can't find a way to fit any of the entries of the definition of 'kin' in this context. Anyone?

EDIT, I actually misunderstood `kin` for `ken`. The kick back from the previous statement shows it:

> Sheldon: "Woman, you're playing with forces beyond your ken."
>   Penny: "Yeah, well your Ken can kiss my Barbie".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably *ken*, not *kin*. *Ken* means, among other things,  'mental perception or recognition'. *Kin* means, more or less, relatives.

Comment: And ken vs kin makes it a fun (ish) malapropism. The forces are not only beyond their understanding, they are beyond the understanding of any relatives, too.

Answer (score 5):

It is probably supposed to be

> beyond your ken.

ken means knowledge, understanding or cognizance.